# Setting Domain with /odoo for Odoo as proxy

Tags: apache, odoo, odoo-website

I have a requirement where domain/odoo will be used as proxy in front of Odoo. So the odoo instance running on ip:8069 directly redirects to /web and the css files etc aren't loaded while using this setup. Is there anyway where I can override this behaviour in Odoo?

Thanks And Regards,

Yaseen Shareef

Comment: Is it possible to just use a subdomain instead? Something like `odoo.my-domain.com`? Would be a simpler / more elegant route to take.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the only solution. There's no way we can have the sub-directory structure in Odoo for domains